# Accessing an external webcam using openCV with C

Tags: c, opencv

I want to access an external webcam connected to the C6748 DSP processor. I used Code Composer Studio (CCS) v 5.5.0 to run the code below. When I compiled the code, I got the following errors.
(A). unable to open the source file cv.h
(B). unable to open the source file types.h

Could someone please help me resolve these errors? I'm using openCV 2.1 .Please let me know the supporting files to be included in CCS before compiling the program.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    IplImage* color_img;
    CvCapture* cv_cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1); // -1 = only one cam or doesn't matter
    cvNamedWindow("Video",1); // create window
    for(;;) {
        color_img = cvQueryFrame(cv_cap); // get frame
        if(color_img != 0)
            cvShowImage("Video", color_img); // show frame
        c = cvWaitKey(10); // wait 10 ms or for key stroke
        if(c == 27)
            break; // if ESC, break and quit
    }
    /* clean up */
    cvReleaseCapture( &cv_cap );
    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
}
```

Comment: Offtopic but main should return int

Answer (score 0):

`#include <cv.h>`

`#include <highgui.h>`

Because you're using `<cv.h>` instead of `"cv.h"`, the compiler needs to be told where to find the files.
You need to tell CCS the directory where these files are located (the 'include' directory). I don't know if CCS uses makefiles or a "Preferences" dialog, but surely it can do this. A quick google search turned this up: https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/75768

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running the code by typing   #include "cv.h" instead of   #include <cv.h> (as I thought cv.h is a user defined library). However, same errors popped up even with "cv.h"

Comment: Using `#include "cv.h"` instructs the compiler to look in the same directory as this source file, to find cv.h.  Using <>brackets instead: `#include <cv.h>` instructs the compiler to look for the file in a predetermined path. You need to tell the compiler what that predetermined path is. 
For instance, if the file was located in _C:/opencv/2.1/cv.h_, you want to add the directory _C:/opencv/2.1/_ to the list of directories the compiler searches through.

The link I provided should tell you how to do this in CCS.